# What is "a sprinkling of blood" in 1 Peter 1:2

Tags: greek, grammar, 1-peter, sacrifice

> κατὰ (**according to**) πρόγνωσιν (**foreknowledge**) Θεοῦ (**of God**) Πατρός (**Father**) ἐν (**by**) ἁγιασμῷ (**a sanctification**) Πνεύματος (**of spirit**) εἰς (**into**) ὑπακοὴν (**obedience**) καὶ (**and**) ῥαντισμὸν (**a sprinkling**) αἵματος (**of blood**) Ἰησοῦ (**of Yeshua**) Χριστοῦ (**Messiah**)

Here is the Berean Literal Bible (take notice of the italics):

> "according to *the* foreknowledge of God *the* Father, by *the* sanctification of *the* Spirit unto *the* obedience and sprinkling of *the* blood of Jesus Christ: May grace and peace be multiplied to you."

I noticed that "sprinkling" is a noun and not a verb, so that this verse is definitely **not** saying

> "[the act of] sprinkling blood"

But rather,

> "a sprinkling (or: a small, thinly distributed amount) of blood".

So I have two questions:

Can this "sprinkling of blood" be understood as a metaphor for "purification"?

If so, then is this verse saying that:

> the scattered are elected according to the foreknowledge of God, by [means of] a sanctification of [their individual]  spirit, [which brings them] into [the same] obedience and purification of Yeshua?

I'm just wondering if there is anything about the grammar that makes this interpretation impossible. Thank you.

Comment: Is there not a strong 1st Passover reference here ([small amount of] blood of lamb without defect as precursor to becoming the people of God: 1:2, 18-19, 2:9-10, cf Exodus 12:4-7, 19:6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The allusion is to Exodus 24:8:

> Exo 24:8  Moses took the blood, sprinkled it on the people, and said,
>   "This is the blood of the covenant which the LORD made with you based
>   on all these words."

However, it is not a reference to the ratification/participation in the Mosaic covenant but rather of the New Covenant with the houses of Israel and Judah, ratified by the death of Jesus:

> Heb_12:24  to Jesus, the mediator of a new covenant, and to the
>   sprinkled blood that speaks a better message than Abel's.

Comment: Thank you WoundedEgo. I'm having trouble seeing a connection between "a sprinkling of blood" and the sprinkling of water. (Just to let you know, you accidentally wrote "Paul was writing.." instead of Peter; those in Asia turned away from Paul- 2 Timothy 1:15). I'm seeing a strong connection between the blood that was sprinkled in the door-posts during Passover (Exodus 12), as well as Exodus 24:6-8, when Moses sprinkled blood on the Israelites and they made a covenant to "be obedient to YHVH". I have a few more questions I'm going to post. Maybe I've lost it, but I'm seeing something very deep.

Comment: @anonymouswho   As I read it the sprinkle cleanses *from* the defilement of blood rather than being made clean *by* blood. I don't see the connection with Lev 17:6 or Num 18:3.

Comment: Ah..nice. I see what you're saying. However, I think we might have a problem with 1 Peter 1:19 (precious blood is in the dative case) , or I may just need to think about it longer. Yeshua died on Passover, so I feel like his blood should have a connection with it. Of course, when I say his blood, I don't mean his literal blood. Lev. 17:14 says the life of all creatures **is** the blood, so I'm considering blood is simply a metaphor for "purification of life" or "precious life"; where his sacrifice was not his death, but his obedience. Oh, and David wrote about Lev. 17:6 and Num. 18:3.

Comment: Hello @David. I'm also having trouble seeing a connection with Lev. 17:6 and Num. 18:3. Could you provide an answer to explain what you think this means? Thank you.

Comment: If my take proved not to be cogent then I would be looking to Exodus 24:8: https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ex+24%3A8&version=NASB;WLC

Comment: @Davïd  I edited my post to take the covenant into account.

Comment: @WoundedEgo- Yes! Exodus 24:8 is exactly what I was thinking. That's what I meant in my first comment. I was torn between Exodus 24:6-8 or 12:7. In Exodus 24:7, the Israelites vowed to "be obedient", so there seems to be a strong correlation there. Since this is making sense to all three of us, it may be something we want to look into further (if you're interested of course). I'm interested because I don't read Paul's letters anymore, so it's nice to think that the apostle Yeshua chose above the rest could write something this deep.

Comment: @anonymouswho  I modified my answer.

Comment: @WoundedEgo- Okay, I agree that Peter is referring to the blood of the new covenant, and I understand what you're saying. I'm just having trouble finding a valid reason for why blood should be understood as water...**However**, I can't help but think of John 19:34. I hope I'm not bothering you with my constant criticism, but I feel like you know better than most here that we have to be critical of every detail until we can finally make sense of a thing. Otherwise we might as well believe in that triune god that hates mankind and needed his own blood to "atone" for 10% of the populations sins.

Comment: @anonymouswho  I think this is a Greek issue. I'll start a new question.

Comment: @anonymouswho  Okay, please see the revelatory discussion https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/23578/in-1-peter-12-why-is-of-blood-in-the-genitive and my new answer.

Comment: Thank you WoundedEgo. Actually, I'm even more convinced that Peter wrote 1 Peter and Hebrews now. The Hebrews 12:24 verse you provided has "αἵματι ῥαντισμοῦ", so it's the same use of "sprinkling" as a noun (but this time sprinkling is genitive and blood is dative). I like this answer, but would you agree or disagree that "a sprinkling of blood" is a metaphor for "purification"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43273/discussion-between-woundedego-and-anonymouswho).

Answer (score 0):

The same as that “better sprinkling” in Heb 12:24, intimately linked to the solemn inauguration of the “blood covenant” at Lk 22:20, the Last Supper. Many overlook that that solemn inauguration (the Supper) was offered on Zion, on 14 Nisan (which Jewish tradition holds was the date of Abel and Cain’s sacrifices), allowing the author of Heb to kaleidoscope the Abel and Jesus offerings together in one continuum. Not only that, but the author cleverly sees Abel as the perfect priest-type for this particular offering, given that Abel’s blood(s) (2 offerings) were specified, as the Hebrew plural in Gen 4:10 hints, exactly corresponding to Jesus’ offering first at the Supper, only later then his own sacrificial death.  A brilliant and insightful handling of all this by a Reformed exegete can be found here: https://legacy.tyndalehouse.com/Bulletin/67=2016/Kim-10.pdf

Jesus not only offered in continuity with Abel (though infinitely more eloquently), but like Abel, offered blood “from the ground”. That is to say the offering of Jesus’ blood has AN EARTHLY COUNTERPART, linking heaven and earth in just one offering. How can a sacrifice be offered in heaven, among those who need one! This is the better oblation, offered [from the Earth] from the rising of the son to its setting (Mal 1:11) which alone appeases and pleases Yahweh.

Comment: Hi Dr, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think the Bible reading at 1 Peter is clear enough. The blood has to be applied to claim the benefits therein. The practice in testament is a Similitude's of what is expected in practice in the New Testament.

Holy common gave us the blood component as a wine he blessed and call it His blood.

If any believer is challenged in any area of life and you have faith in His blood, take a little of the blood add to water and sprinkle over your household and all your lost peace and absence of grace will return. Remember each believer lives according to his own faith. Shalim

Comment: The second and third paragraphs are obscure and are without substantiation. Please see the Tour and Help (below, bottom left) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.